# What's default dataType of jquery's ajax and get methods?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to know the default value of dataType of `$.ajax()` and `$.get()`?
It's **json** or **html** or others?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/15977958/3639582

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery 1.9 .ajax() datatype default changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977876/jquery-1-9-ajax-datatype-default-changed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **dataType** (default: `Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)`)
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Answer (score 1):

If data type is not specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response

```
dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
```