# Render partial view from a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, partial-views

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app.

I have this in my Index.html page:

```
<div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
    <p>
        Upgrade your Legacy VB6 Applications to .Net Core!
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="VB6Upgrades">
            Learn More
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="MainContent" class="row">

</div>
```

My JS file:

```
$("#VB6Upgrades").click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("LoadVB6Upgrades","/Home")', {}, function (response) {
        $("#MainContent").html(response);
    });
});
```

My Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        ViewData["RequestId"] = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult LoadVB6Upgrades()
    {
        return PartialView("_LoadVB6Upgrades");
    }
}
```

When I click my link the Index() function is invoked?

What should I be doing please?

Comment: Try adding `href="#"` as a quick fix to the `a` element in your HTML. Also note that you don't need the `/` before `/Home` in the controller argument of `Url.Action()`

Comment: in your get statement, just use $.get('/HomeController/LoadVB6Upgrades', function(){});

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks did that but all I get is that page loaded into that div :(

Comment: Is that not what you're trying to do? Your code is making an AJAX request to get the HTML which it then places in to the `#MainContent` dialog

Comment: If you're trying to load it into a modal, then you need to design the _LoadVB6Upgrades.html page to be in modal view

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan re: '/' thanks

Comment: @Keith thanks i am not. i am trying to load it into my DIV called MainContent

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry should have been more explicit :). What I meant was that the Index.cshtml page was being loaded into that DIV and not my Partial View called _LoadVB6Upgrades.cshtml

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also, if i do not include the '/' my controller is not called

Comment: @Keith  Itried the $.get you suggested but still the same result

Comment: for the response, does it bring back the html from your page?

Comment: yes the whole vIew and not the partial.

Comment: so, what is happening is its bringing back html, no matter if its partial or full. The page doesn't get rendered partially, it gets rendered based on the parameters you set around it. So your #MainContent section needs to be set according to your width and height. The partial you're bringing back, I would rip off the css and see what it looks like in the area you provided, and then add the css back in to what you want

Comment: @Keith The issue stems from the fact that my LoadVB6Upgrades method in my controller is not being called.  The index is.  So, the Ajax call is not correct for some reason though I do not know why. The partialview has no css. It just says <div>hello</div>

Comment: maybe use ActionResult instead of IActionResult

Comment: @Keith tried all of these including Partial. i have not touched web for 2 years (and it shows!). just weird

Comment: oh maybe use public partial class HomeController...

Comment: maybe it is to do with asp.net core..  need to Google :( Thanks for trying to help me.  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you have to set datatype as html for load partial view in div. default data type is json you can check here [stackoverflow.com/questions/30953714/whats-default-datatype-of-jquerys-ajax-and-get-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953714/whats-default-datatype-of-jquerys-ajax-and-get-methods)

```
  $("#VB6Upgrades").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadVB6Upgrades","Home")',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                     $("#MainContent").html(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
             $("#MainContent").html('');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to set datatype as html to load html data like partial view and default is json it is used to return json results