# Trying to inject one html page into another after an AJAX call but returning blank

Tags: html, django, ajax

I'm trying to inject an html template with a django function on it, into another html template. The function rests on an AJAX call for its variables.

My AJAX call seems to be firing correctly (after checking in the Chrome dev tools) but the result is not showing on the html page as it should be.

Here is the AJAX call

```
//dashboard
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Document Ready')
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
             url : '/electra/playlist',
             dataType: "json",
             data: {
                 'venue': 'venue',
                 'list':  'list',
                },
                    success: function(data){
                    $("#playlist").html(data);
                    console.log(data)
                    },
                    failure: function(errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                    });
    });
```

Here is the html file where the Django function occurs `playlist.html`

```
<!--what is the purpose of this fragmented code?-->
<div class="user_playlists">
  <ul>
    {% for item in playlist %}
      <li>
        <div>
            <h6 class="playlist-name">{{ item.list }}</h6>
            <h6 class="venue-name">{{ item.venue }}</h6>
        </div>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the portion of the `dashboard.html` template where the `playlist.html` function should be injected:

```
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:15px">
          <!--location -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <h3 class="list-heading"> Your Playlists </h3>
              <div id="playlist">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Please note I have tried with `{% include "playlist.html" %}` and would like to avoid this if I can, I have another two html templates working in a similar way with out the django function.

Here is the views.py if it helps as well:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'testingland/dashboard.html')

class user_playlist(ListView):
    template_name = 'testingland/playlist.html'
    context_object_name = 'playlist'
    model = UserVenue

    def get_queryset(self):
        venue = self.request.GET.get('venue', None)
        list = self.request.GET.get('list', None)

        return UserVenue.objects.filter(list__user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send *json* type data. So, just removing the line should work fine:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : '/electra/playlist',
            // dataType: "json", ---> Remove this line
            data: {
                'venue': 'venue',
                'list':  'list',
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#playlist").html(data);
                console.log(data)
            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    });
```

Note:- *"Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."*  - [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Oh thank you! That fixed it. I will accept this answer when I can (5 minutes according to stack). Can you explain why the json was the cause of the error? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget to see the deprecated notice from jQuery. :)

Comment: @deadant88 `dataType` is the type of data that is responded from the server. And, it's [default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953746/10860596) values are `(xml, json, script, or html)`. As, you are expecting `html` type data and not `json` type. By specifying, you are restricting to get only `json` type data. So, the line was removed. I hope you are clear about what I am trying to say!!!